# What does it mean for Rails merge to win a where clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) says, "If we do want the last where clause to win then Relation#merge can be used."

In the below example, why use merge if you can just have `User.where(User.inactive)`?

```
User.active.merge(User.inactive)
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."state" = 'inactive'
```

Comment: I think your question should be which where clause wins a merge - and I'm pretty sure it means which gets prioritised in the merge

Answer (score 0):

`User.active.merge(User.inactive)` - you've applied two opposite scopes. `state = "active"` and `state = "inactive"`. Joined with `AND` they will make you query nothing (`state = "active" AND state = "inactive"`). I think they said that `merge` will beat a scope used before `#merge`.